# Sitecore hide web database from the sitecore desktop

Tags: sitecore

I need to hide the "web" database being displayed in the toolbar(databases) in Sitecore desktop for certain user roles(We don't need these people to give access to web database). How can I do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What I did was go into the `Core` database and hide the Database selector completely (in our case there's no need for them to change databases - we only have `Core`, `Master`, `Web`).

In the `Core` database, you can go to `/sitecore/content/Applications/Desktop/Tray/Database` and remove read rights there. I believe what I did was create a new role which removes inheritance there, so if you do have users that need it they can get a different role which explicitly allows it.